# Java - Runtime.getRuntime().exec() what's going on?

Tags: java, runtime, exec, runtime.exec

I have problem with Runtime.exec() in Java 
My code:

```
String lol = "/home/pc/example.txt";
String[] b = {"touch", lol}; 
try {  
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(b);  
} catch(Exception ex) {  
    doSomething(ex);  
}
```

It's working good but when I trying changle variable "lol" files doesn't create in hard disk

for instance:
`String lol = x.getPath();` where getPath() returns String

What should I do ?

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Haven't done a lot of Java on Linux, but possibly a permissions issue -- maybe the sandbox doesn't let you create files outside the home dir?  Just a guess, maybe something to look into.

Comment: Thx for reply but I set chmod 777 and when I don't use getPath() file turn up.

Comment: Note: `Runtime#exec()` doesn't throw any exception if the command failed. You'd like to read its output or error stream. Also see this link (all the 4 pages) http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution to your problem . I faced a similar problem and this worked for me by specefying the output directory, it should execute the output of your files in that working directory.

```
   ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("<YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH>" + "abc.exe"); // <your executable path> 
   proc.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);  // 
   proc.directory(fi); // fi = your output directory
   proc.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a `java.io.File`
In that case `getPath()` doesn't return the absolute path.
For example:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // Prints "/home/pc/"
// This means that all files with an relative path will be located in "/home/pc/"
File file = new File("example.txt");
// Now the file, we are pointing to is: "/home/pc/example.txt"
System.out.println(file.getPath()); // Prints "example.txt"
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); // Prints "/home/pc/example.txt"
```

So, conclusion: use `java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()`.

Tip: there also exists a `java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile()` method. This will return the absolute path when calling `getPath()`.

---

I just read your comment to the other answer:

I think you did:

```
String[] cmd = {"touch /home/pc/example.txt"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

This won't work, because the os searches for an application called "`touch /home/pc/example.txt`".
Now, you are thinking "WTF? Why?"
Because the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String cmd);` splits your string up on the spaces.
And `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray);` doesn't split it up. So, you have to do it by yourself:

```
String[] cmd = {"touch", "/home/pc/example.txt"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply look at the content of lol, when you called `x.getPath()`. I would guess it is not an absolute path and the file gets created, but not where you expect it to be.

It `x` is a `Java.io.File` us `getCanonicalPath()` for an absolute path.

Comment: Good point but if I print x.getPath() gets result equals "/home/pc/example.txt". It's should be OK. When I using  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch /home/pc/example.txt") it's work fine, but when I trying using function it's doesen't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works when you set the string to the literal "/home/pc/example.txt", and x.getPath also returns the same value, then it MUST work - it's as simple as that. Which means that x.getPath() is actually returning something else. Maybe there's whitespace in the string? Try comparing the strings directly:

```
if (!"/home/pc/example.txt".equals(x.getPath())) throw new RuntimeException();
```

Answer (score 0):

like write code for real path

```
String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

here u can get real path ..........